# How can I resolve DeadLock due to KeyLock in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have following two tables in my SQL Server

**adjustment_details_backup**

```
+---------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
| Name                      | Owner   | Type       | Created_datetime        |
|---------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------|
| adjustment_details_backup | dbo     | user table | 2019-05-29 06:10:18.990 |
+---------------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
 
+---------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
| Column_name   | Type     | Computed   | Length   | Prec   | Scale   | Nullable   |
|---------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
| id            | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| cid           | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| promotion_id  | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| adjustment_id | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| target_type   | varchar  | no         | 10       |        |         | no         |
| target_ids    | nvarchar | no         | -1       |        |         | no         |
| bf_ids        | nvarchar | no         | -1       |        |         | yes        |
+---------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
 
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| index_name                     | index_description                                     | index_keys        |
|--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------|
| adj_details_backup_cid_pid_idx | clustered                                             | promotion_id, cid |
| PK__adjustme__3213E83E9278D5B8 | nonclustered, unique, primary key, stats no recompute | id                |
| UQ__adjustme__323248487A244F7A | nonclustered, unique, unique key, stats no recompute  | adjustment_id     |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+

+-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| constraint_type             | constraint_name                | delete_action   | update_action   | status_enabled   | status_for_replication   | constraint_keys                                                                                     |
|-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| CHECK on column target_type | CK__adjustmen__targe__2180FB33 | (n/a)           | (n/a)           | Enabled          | Is_For_Replication       | ([target_type]='CORPORATE' OR [target_type]='STATE' OR [target_type]='DC' OR [target_type]='STORE') |
| FOREIGN KEY                 | FK__adjustmen__adjus__22751F6C | No Action       | No Action       | Enabled          | Is_For_Replication       | adjustment_id                                                                                       |
|                             |                                |                 |                 |                  |                          | REFERENCES forecast-management.dbo.adjustments (id)                                                 |
| PRIMARY KEY (non-clustered) | PK__adjustme__3213E83E9278D5B8 | (n/a)           | (n/a)           | (n/a)            | (n/a)                    | id                                                                                                  |
| UNIQUE (non-clustered)      | UQ__adjustme__323248487A244F7A | (n/a)           | (n/a)           | (n/a)            | (n/a)                    | adjustment_id                                                                                       |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**promotion_adj_details**

```
+-----------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
| Name                  | Owner   | Type       | Created_datetime        |
|-----------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------|
| promotion_adj_details | dbo     | user table | 2019-08-06 03:53:43.430 |
+-----------------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
 
+-----------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
| Column_name     | Type      | Computed   | Length   | Prec   | Scale   | Nullable   |
|-----------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
| id              | int       | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| promotion_id    | int       | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| cid             | int       | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| created_on      | datetime  | no         | 8        |        |         | no         |
| modified_on     | datetime  | no         | 8        |        |         | no         |
| adj_json_zipped | varbinary | no         | -1       |        |         | no         |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
 
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
| index_name                     | index_description                | index_keys        |
|--------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------|
| PK__promotio__3213E83FE8FA2571 | clustered, unique, primary key   | id                |
| promotion_adj_details_cid_idx  | nonclustered                     | cid               |
| promotion_adj_details_pid_idx  | nonclustered                     | promotion_id      |
| UQ__promotio__C13A286F425A6973 | nonclustered, unique, unique key | promotion_id, cid |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

**adjustments**

```
+-------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
| Name        | Owner   | Type       | Created_datetime        |
|-------------+---------+------------+-------------------------|
| adjustments | dbo     | user table | 2019-05-09 08:15:14.477 |
+-------------+---------+------------+-------------------------+
 
+---------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
| Column_name         | Type     | Computed   | Length   | Prec   | Scale   | Nullable   |
|---------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
| id                  | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| promotion_id        | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| cid                 | int      | no         | 4        | 10     | 0       | no         |
| adjustment_type     | varchar  | no         | 10       |        |         | no         |
| adjustment_value    | decimal  | no         | 9        | 10     | 2       | no         |
| created_on          | datetime | no         | 8        |        |         | no         |
| created_by          | char     | no         | 100      |        |         | no         |
| week_wise_adj_value | nvarchar | no         | -1       |        |         | yes        |
| is_deleted          | bit      | no         | 1        |        |         | yes        |
+---------------------+----------+------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+
 
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| index_name                                          | index_description                                  | index_keys        |
|-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------|
| cid_adjustments_idx                                 | nonclustered, stats no recompute                   | cid               |
| nci_wi_adjustments_034DD80FB7DC1D4D53A547E27C1529C0 | nonclustered                                       | cid, promotion_id |
| PK__adjustme__3213E83F515209F6                      | clustered, unique, primary key, stats no recompute | id                |
| promotion_id_adjustments_idx                        | nonclustered                                       | promotion_id      |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

**Queries Involved in a Transaction**

1.

```
update promotion_adj_details set
    adj_json_zipped = @P0
    , cid = @P1
    , created_on = @P2
    , modified_on = @P3
    , promotion_id = @P4
where id = @P5
```

Depicted in screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EItX.png)

Query Plan :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryKPqWbuu

2.

```
update adjustments set is_deleted=1 where promotion_id = ? AND cid = ?
```

This query was not involved in the deadlock graph

Query Plan: `https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkFlDf-O_`

3.

```
delete
from adjustment_details_backup
where promotion_id = ? and cid = ?
```

Depicted in screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExXgG.png)

Query Plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkqfIGWud

**Deadlock Graph**

Deadlock graph [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVs9I.png)

XML

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process2d442314108" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process2d442314108" taskpriority="0" logused="1372" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594132824064 (607d869ecbe8)" waittime="4953" ownerId="8556751122" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-05-04T12:07:47.353" XDES="0x26a64638428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="8" kpid="162728" status="suspended" spid="302" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-05-04T12:07:47.570" lastbatchcompleted="2021-05-04T12:07:47.370" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.370" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-gzjwp" hostpid="0" loginname="sfadmin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="8556751122" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x8153068d505a8ecd" queryplanhash="0xdb0a1e522d176238" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="398" sqlhandle="0x0200000091cf3b15cbb8ede6d04926ce1c187fecb662f6bf0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@P0 varbinary(max),@P1 bigint,@P2 datetime2,@P3 datetime2,@P4 int,@P5 int)update promotion_adj_details set adj_json_zipped=@P0, cid=@P1, created_on=@P2, modified_on=@P3, promotion_id=@P4 where id=@P5                                                   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process26a9a2d3088" taskpriority="0" logused="237020" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594165460992 (ee71f83cca9f)" waittime="3332" ownerId="8556751061" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-05-04T12:07:47.333" XDES="0x2d48dde0428" lockMode="X" schedulerid="7" kpid="159308" status="suspended" spid="234" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-05-04T12:07:49.197" lastbatchcompleted="2021-05-04T12:07:47.353" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.353" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="forecast-mgmt-747b85c647-dspv8" hostpid="0" loginname="sfadmin" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="8556751061" currentdb="5" currentdbname="forecast-management" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x7e867b2565e65832" queryplanhash="0x710c23602e4594bd" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="182" sqlhandle="0x02000000e5e51d33143ba4604e142e0a55339e8320e190550000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x7e867b2565e65832" queryplanhash="0x710c23602e4594bd" line="1" stmtend="164" sqlhandle="0x020000003c172b0091203fa10d2b2443b8a665d70bed1f2b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
delete from adjustment_details_backup where promotion_id = 29510 AND cid = 23476054   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594132824064" dbid="5" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.promotion_adj_details" indexname="PK__promotio__3213E83FE8FA2571" id="lock26b1d077300" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594132824064">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process26a9a2d3088" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2d442314108" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594165460992" dbid="5" objectname="66b54972-a069-4426-a3c9-393f898368f6.dbo.adjustment_details_backup" indexname="adj_details_backup_cid_pid_idx" id="lock25f10438f00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594165460992">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2d442314108" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process26a9a2d3088" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

**QUESTION**

Here both the tables have no relation amongst themselves. Why has this deadlock occurred? How is the keylock working internally in SQL Server? How to avoid this?

Comment: Are you running either of these in a transaction? Are there triggers on either table. Please share the query plans for both queries via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: yes ... these commands are being run in a transaction . The single transaction contains both these commands

Comment: Please [edit] and add the SQL for the full batch of queries, along with table *and index* definitions, and share the query plans as mentioned. The transaction appears to be holding onto locks while the next query is run

Comment: Hi @Charlieface , Thanks for your response . I have added the details . I am wondering if adjustment_details_backup.adjustment_id which is the foreign key to adjustments table causing the issue

Comment: OK so what's happened is that sessionid 302 has already updated a row on a particular page in `adjustment_details_backup` and holds an X lock til the end of the tran, it is now trying to update `promotion_adj_details` and requesting a U lock to check for rows to update. But session 234 has already updated a row on that page, and is itself trying to take an X lock on the *original* page from `adjustment_details_backup` that session 302 locked, hence the deadlock. I can only assume: either you are executing these queries out of order, or you are executing them in a loop on different rows, ....

Comment: .... while still in the same transaction. Whichever of those it is needs fixing. You must always access tables and indexes in the same order. If the latter, then you need a set-based solution where you can update all rows you need to in one table, before moving on to the other table, and do not go back to the first without committing

Comment: Hi @Charlieface , I have checked my Application code . There is nowhere in code having the order of queries as adjustment_details_backup -> promotion_adj_details . The order is maintained throughout the system as adjustments -> promotion_adj_details -> adjustment_details_backup.

Comment: adjustments has either save/update query .....
promotion_adj_details can have save/delete/update query ......
adjustment_details_backup has save/delete query.

Comment: So are you executing the whole thing in a loop? How are you starting the transaction, client-side or via SQL? Can you upload the *full* text of each batch, I don't understand what you mean when you say there are different queries?

Comment: I found a deadlock possibility between adjustments and promotion_adj_details entity. Queries applied on these two tables are in different order in the code at two places . Looks like this is the cause. Correcting the sequence of queries . Thanks @Charlieface